# strange messages in log file @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^

Tags: java, logging, nohup, apache-mina

I have a application server for network operations written with Java based on Apache Mina. Recently I encounter a strange behavior in my log files. I noticed that the log file is full of @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^.... characters. I mean those unexpected characters are vast amount of as such the log file gets hundreds of GB in a couple of hours! I have no clue about this problem and it is almost impossible to google it. What could be the reason? Are those set of characters any familiar to anybody?

I can give more details about the application if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The messages are possibly a bug in the code doing the logging or, as i've experienced, a malicious attempt to crack the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those characters are [null characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (NUL, ASCII value 0) in [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).

> In caret notation for control characters the null character is ^@.

Comment: If you are using vim, try ":set nobomb" to display their real nature